# best way to use getResourceAsStream for jar file in java

Tags: java, jar

My jar file can't find my data.txt file with the code below:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"))) {
}
```

So I am trying to use `getResourceAsStream`.
What is the best way to use it that does exactly the same as my code above?
This is how my files are stored:

```
-Project
   -src
      -a.java
      -b.jav
   -data.txt
```

Comment: Your text- file must be in the classapath

Comment: Add a `/` before the file name. `new FileReader("/data.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
String sFileName = "/data.txt";
String sFileToRead = getClass().getResource().getFile(sFileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(sFileToRead)));
```